# How to create jigsaw module in SBT?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-11, module-info

I would like to use jlink for creating self-contained application packages for all platforms (darwin, linux, windows) from Scala source code. It seems that `jlink` only works with new (relatively) jigsaw modules - so I need to package my code as a module. In Java world it seems to be easily achieved by placing special module-info.java file to the package that will become a module.

I tried to follow intuition and just placed this module-info.java into `src/main/java/my.package.name/module-info.java`. Though this doesn't work. It seems that `scalac` is trying to read module-info.java as usual Java file (which is not the case), hence the error

> ```
> module-info.java:1:8: illegal start of type declaration
> [error] module my.package.name {
> [error]        ^
> ```

What do I need to do to package my Scala code as a module?

Open JDK: 11
Scala: 2.12.4
SBT: 1.1.6

Comment: If scalac doesn't know anything about modules then you might have to compile the module-info.java separately, with javac -d specifying the output directory where the scalac compiler has emitted the class files for the contents of the module.

Answer (score 4):

In general seems like that scala doesn't completely support Java9+, at least [their compatibility notes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html#jdk-9--up-compatibility-notes) read so.

> As of Scala 2.12.6 and 2.11.12, JDK 9+ support is incomplete. Notably,
>   scalac will not enforce the restrictions of the Java Platform Module
>   System, which means that code that typechecks may incur linkage errors
>   at runtime. Scala 2.13.x will provide rudimentary support for this,
>   but likely only in nightlies built on Java 11.

You can follow [Support features of JDK 9+](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139) and [Java 11 testing](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/559) for further updates.